# Dynamic Layout for EasyUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

Using jQuery and EasyUI, I would like to know how to dynamically create a layout.  The following is my attempt; however is doesn't appear to work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CTest Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/lib/jquery-easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/lib/jquery-easyui/themes/icon.css">                
        <script data-main="app/app" src="app/lib/require-js/require.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body></body>
</html>
```

My app.js

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "app/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "/app",
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min",
      "easyui": "jquery-easyui/jquery.easyui.min"
    }
});
define(["jquery"], function($){ 
    require(["easyui"],function(){
        require(["app/views/viewport"],function(){
        });
    });
});
```

My viewport.js

```
//Layout the page
$('body').addClass("easyui-layout");
$('body').append("<div id='spa-head' data-options=\"region:'north'\"></div>");
$('body').append("<div id='spa-west' data-options=\"region:'west',width:300,split:true\"></div>");
$('body').append("<div id='spa-cntr' data-options=\"region:'center',title:'CENTER'\"></div>");
```

The page should have rendered a layout with regions for north, west and center. The center panel would have been titled and the west panel would have had a resizable splitter. Instead, the page was blank even though I could see the proper elements rendered in the console.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would helpful if you could add a little more to "it doesn't appear to work" - how does it fail / what does it do compared to what you were expecting it to do?

Comment: Greetings and thanks.  The page should have rendered a layout with regions for north, west and center.  The center panel would have been titled and the west panel would have had a resizable splitter.  Instead the page was bank even though I could see the proper elements rendered in the console.

Comment: Excellent.  [Press the edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28768046/edit) under your post and add that info into the question.  Unfortunately I'm not an EasyUI expert so not sure I can actually solve for you, but probably someone will come along who can.  It just came to me for review (all first posts come to a user with >2k rep for review).

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the layout on document ready as,

```
 $('body').layout();
```